# SonarQube exclude based on date?

Tags: sonarqube

Now that the Cutoff date plugin for Sonar is deprecated (I've tried it, and it doesn't seem to work at all), **is there any way to exclude issues based on a set date?**

For a large project, it is desirable to really start at fresh at given point. 
Maintaining a low alert threshold ( < 100 alerts ) is much more manageable for the developers than cluttering the issues listings with old history/low priority issues. (1500++). Identifying the new and relevant ones are then much harder.

What we want to focus on are new issues. 
Example: 
when you have changed the quality rules for say 200.000+ lines of code, you really only are interested in what is produced from now on and changes to already existing code that breaks the new rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my feeling is correct, you're not aware of the way to work with differential periods in SonarQube. Because out-of-the-box SonarQube is designed to cover such common use case. See :
http://www.sonarqube.org/differentials-four-ways-to-see-whats-changed/
http://www.sonarqube.org/using-differentials-to-move-the-team-in-the-right-direction/
http://www.sonarqube.org/differentials-but-wait-theres-more/

Comment: I do know about the diff view. However, we do not feel that this gives ut what we need. That is, hide all alerts from old legacy code from the alert views. Setting the alert threshold at < 50 issues is far more manageable than setting the threshold at < 2000 issues. The old issues just clutters the views and makes configuring the buildbreaker plugin harder. (which must be based on last x days / given date) And experience tells us that it is hard to make all developers actively check the differential views. (arhitects/leads do this)

Comment: Hi. After a quick discussion we have commited to diff views. Configuring break levels for BOTH last X days AND total issue counts should cover our need. Thanks for input!